# UI Bootstrap Alert using AngularJS ng-hide takes up extra space

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a simple UI Bootstrap alert that I use to show error messages etc.
I hide it (by default) just below a header at the top of my page.
I can change the colour and the text using scope variables, and use ng-hide to hide it. Here is the alert html:

```
<alert type={{alertType}} close="hideAlert = true"
    ng-hide="hideAlert" class="ng-hide">{{alertText}}</alert>
```

The problem is that when the page loads, and the alert is hidden, there is an extra 20px or so of space taken up by the hidden alert. When I inspect the elements, it seems that the 'x' close button takes up 21px of space, and is not being shrunk like the alert is. This is what shows up in the elements console,

```
<button ng-show="closeable" type="button" class="close" ng-click="close($event)">
    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</button>
```

Also, the text element of the alert is doing the same thing, except on 20px of space - though this space is contained in the 21px above. The element console shows this:

```
<div ng-transclude="">
    <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Default Alert!</span>
</div>
```

The CSS for the alert and alert.ng-hide looks like this:

```
.alert {
    -moz-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;

    display: block !important;
    max-height:50px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.alert.ng-hide {
    display: block !important;
    max-height:0px;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Any ideas why these alert components are not being shrunk when hidden?

Comment: I am not %100 sure but instead of ng-hide you could may be use ng-if. ng-hide draws and hides object ng-if directly destroys dom. May be using ng-if should solve your problem. No dom object could mean no pixel occupation in screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the problem is with your CSS line `display: block !important;`  When `hideAlert` is true, UI Bootstrap applies a `display:none;` to the alert which hides it entirely but this is being overwritten by the `display:block !important`.

I'm also not sure why you need to supply the `ng-hide` value for the class attribute within the `alert` element.

I also agree with ibrahimbayer that using ng-if would solve the problem.